# Fowler-Nordheim tunneling following high voltage and voltage breakdowns in X-ray tubes

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, voltage, x-rays

I am taking some measurements concerning a vacuum based X-ray tube. One has to ramp up the voltage slowly in a process called conditioning of the tube. Without allowing a current to flow along the cathode filament, one observes nevertheless a (leak) current due to field emission (FE) and other processes due to (FE). The measurements I take are this current and the voltage. Along the voltage augmentation (in the order of some hundreds of kV) one observes regularly voltage breakdowns. It's ubiquitous that during such a breakdown the current increases and the voltage decreases rapidly. I need to show what these voltage breakdowns are due to. In particular, I need to show if the measurements are in line with the Fowler-Nordheim plot.

1. What is the usual way to present the Fowler-Nordheim plot given the data I have? Which part of the data should I plot, i.e. only the voltage and current from the pre-breakdown to after breakdown for each such voltage breakdown or the whole data?
2. How should the plot look like in order to claim that the voltage breakdown is due to FE as predicted by the Fowler-Nordheim? If it doesn't look as expected what should one conclude given what we know to date about FE in the regime of high voltage.
3. One also observes frequently during a voltage breakdown that the current and the voltage start the rapid change at the same time point and thus different from what is described in the literature according to which the leak current "announces" the voltage breakdown so that the current starts changing prior to the voltage change. Does it make sense in that case to represent the Fowler-Nordheim plot?

I will appreciate if you approach the one or the other question.